# NotificationCompat.Builder, How to get the exact intent with addAction?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Notification Action with 2 buttons. 
I want to do this with `PendingIntent.getActivities` which get `intents[]` as one of the parameters.
The problem is with `mBuilder.addAction`, I can't choose what intent to run when the user clicks a button. 
Right now each button activate the same intent.
I'm sure that there is must be something I can choose what intent I want to select, otherwise why `intent[]` was one of the parameters for `getActivities()` method?

Tried to search for a solution but no luck..

Here is the main code to show you what I wanted to do exactly:

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

        Intent[] intents = new Intent[2];
        intents[0] =  new Intent(this,next_activity.class); // the first Intent
        intents[1] = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with.."); // the second Intent

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this,0,intents,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// the problem is with resultPendingIntent, need to choose what intent to run from intents array
        mBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Share",resultPendingIntent) 
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Open", resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: each button has same itent because you are passing the same pendingintent. You can create 2 different pending intents and add it

Answer (score 0):

[PendingIntent#getActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent[],%20int))

```
(Context context, int requestCode, Intent[] intents, int flags)
```

> Like getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), but allows an array of Intents to be supplied. The last Intent in the array is taken as the primary key for the PendingIntent, like the single Intent given to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int). Upon sending the resulting PendingIntent, all of the Intents are started in the same way as they would be by passing them to startActivities(Intent[]).

Both actions will start the same intents. Both intents will be started after triggering either action.

Solution?

Retrieve a PendingIntent for the corresponding Intent and attach it to the corresponding action.

```
PendingIntent sharePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intents[1],PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intents[0],PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Share",sharePendingIntent) 
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Open", openPendingIntent);
```

Comment: But what  if I want 3 buttons? I will make 3 instances of PendingIntent? Is there something else to do?